# Dependencias en un WSDL ¿Cómo puedo importarlas en el proyecto?

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse, wsdl

Buenas, estoy en Eclipse montando un proyecto Maven. Todo va bien pero hay un par de clases que me piden dependencias de un webservice y no sé exportarlas para que los demás recursos del proyecto accedan a ella.

¿Alguien sabría las posibilidades que hay?

Muchas gracias.

Edit: Extiendo la pregunta.

Yo tengo por ejemplo un archivo `src/main/java/paquete.servicio/miservicio.java` donde tengo:

```
import paquete.externo.webservice.dependencia1
import paquete.externo.webservice.dependencia2
```

Tengo un JAX-WS Web Services en el proyecto raíz y en `src/main/resources` tengo una carpeta wsdl que tiene un wsdl por ejemplo que contiene dependencia1 y dependencia2.

¿Queda algo más claro?

Comment: ¿Puedes exponer tu caso con más detalles? ¿Has creado las clases para consumir un webservice? ¿Tu proyecto ofrece o consume el servicio?

Comment: Como dice @PabloLozano se necesitaría algo mas de información o al menos algún error que te salte para poder hacernos una idea

Comment: El problema es que el proyecto no es mío, es heredado.
Edito con ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Si tu `wsdl` hace referencia a los otros elementos de una manera similar a:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://xxx:9090/xxxxxx" namespace="xxxxx"/>
```

simplemente descarga el contenido de `http://xxx:9090/xxxxxx` a tu equipo, cópialo a la carpeta donde tienes tu `wsdl` con el nombre `xx.xml`, y cambia la linea anterior por

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="./xx.xml" namespace="xxxxx"/>
```

De esta manera ya tendrías todo enlazado.

Comment: No es exactamente esto lo que buscaba. **SOLUCIÓN**: Encontré la solución, y es que se exportan en la carpeta target. Lo que tenía que hacer es en las propiedades del proyecto ir a "Java Build Parth">"Source" y añadir la carpeta de target dónde están descomprimidas las clases del webservice. De todas maneras tendré en cuenta tu respuesta cuando monte mi propio proyecto :D